# Is the concept of Planck Length in this video corrrect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I'm asking this question because I'm a 10th grader and interested about learning Planck Length. Here's a video I made https://youtu.be/VECJqYCTwbo. Is all the content in this correct. Can I now show it to my teacher?

The edited video as suggested by people at Physics Stack Exchange https://youtu.be/coYqYDS69YU

Comment: BTW, I'm a 10th grader and don't want to be overwhelmed by university level physics

Comment: First of all: It is Planck, not Plank.

Comment: Where does your claim: "Nothing in Quantum Physics has been verified experimentally" come from? I am not sure you know what you are talking about, but quite contrary, almost everything in quantum physics (discrete energy quanta in EM waves, electron orbits in atoms, wave nature of fundamental particles, to name a few) has been verified experimentally, that is why it is used and so successful.

Comment: Also... You CAN say it is not proven that the Planck length is the smallest possible unit of distance... while there are theoretical arguments for that. But the existence of the Planck length itself needs no proof, since it is first of a all just a specific length scale. The existence of a certain length scale does not need a proof, since as a length scale the Planck length definitely "exists" in the same manner as the meter.

Comment: Thanks i fixed it. Now i mention in description that I actually said the wrong thing . Here's the link https://youtu.be/VECJqYCTwbo

Comment: I mentioned in description of video that Most of Quantum Physics is experimentally proven but Plank Length isn't

Comment: To reopen this question consider to make it self-contained.

Comment: @Qmechanic Regardng reopening I would point out that it is ()in effect) a check-my-work question ( IMO ), so a self-contained version is not necessarily a real change.  I wonder if the OP might be better off checking their doubts using a few a single question posts rather than relying on the video to be viewed ?

Comment: @StephenG: Noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Alien has moved in on our street - or someone very similar!

Bet the Alien has better manners though.

Anyway, about the video:

The physics facts seems fine and yes it would be a good way to talk about heights.

For presentation it would be best to try and improve the sound quality, speak more slowly and clearly.  Perhaps its the different accents, but for example between 25 and 35 seconds, it wasn't clear at all.  Maybe less speaking overall would be better, letting people read and think about things on the screen.

Also leave the picture that was on at 1 min 42s, on the screen for longer, so people have a chance to think about it and count the zeros.

Maybe include more about the definition of Planck length given near the top of this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length

All the best with it.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to edit your video and avoid making bold and wrong claims like "nothing in quantum physics is experimentally proven". I will leave you some links to learn what planck length is really about, they should be easy enough to be understood by 10th grader

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length)

[Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2019/06/26/what-is-the-smallest-possible-distance-in-the-universe/?sh=22c5354c48a1)

[South Wales](https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/einsteinlight/jw/module6_Planck.htm)

[Fermilab](https://youtu.be/rzB2R_qiC28)